# How to configure ssl for API in kong

Tags: ssl, kong

I'm working on kong 0.13.1. Following the docs I added certificate as follows:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "cert": "certificate is really here", 
            "created_at": 1529667116000, 
            "id": "6ae77f49-a13f-45b1-a370-8d53b35d7bfd", 
            "key": "The key is really here", 
            "snis": [
                "myapp.local", 
                "mockbin.myapp.local"
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "total": 1
}
```

Then added an API which works perfectly well with http:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "created_at": 1529590900803, 
            "hosts": [
                "mockbin.myapp.local"
            ], 
            "http_if_terminated": false, 
            "https_only": false, 
            "id": "216c23c5-a1ae-4bef-870b-9c278113f8f8", 
            "name": "mockbin", 
            "preserve_host": false, 
            "retries": 5, 
            "strip_uri": true, 
            "upstream_connect_timeout": 60000, 
            "upstream_read_timeout": 60000, 
            "upstream_send_timeout": 60000, 
            "upstream_url": "http://localhost:3000"
        }
    ], 
    "total": 1
}
```

But unfortunately Kong keeps sending me a default cert located in `/usr/local/kong/ssl/kong-default.crt`

I'm testing it with:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443/products -host mockbin.myapp.local -debug
```

Back in the days there was a dynamic ssl plugin (where api ssl was added with version 0.3.0) but it's gone since 0.10 update.

I know that it's kinda fix my <strike>code</strike> configuration question but possibly someone else might also run into similar issue.

Comment: did you ever resolve this, I have the same issue.

Comment: @dweeb not really, I posted a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time on figuring it out but I didn't manage to fix it. As [kong docs](https://docs.konghq.com/0.13.x/admin-api/#api-object) say, api is deprecated so I ended up with rewriting everything to routes and services and I advise you to do the same. Routes and services work perfectly well when implementing step by step based on docs.

Comment: I'm attempting this with my own service using an nginx ingress but no luck, just defaults to the kong cert.

Answer (score 1):

The Kong documentation seems clear on [how to use the administrative api to configure ssl certificates](https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/admin-api/#certificate-object).  It is certainly easier to maintain the certificate at the global level, rather than service and route-specific administration.

Others looking for the answer to this question should find it straightforward, to follow the instructions in the latest Kong documentation linked above.